# how to integrate react externally

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a CMS to build interfaces and need React JS to integrate into the system via CDN links. It gives me an error when trying to load some components. Do I have to explicitly keep loading components or is there some other way? Im using the following links:

`

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="react-container"></div>
<script type="text/babel">

  class Note extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     checked: true,
     activePage: 1
    }
    this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this)
   }

   handleCheck() {
    this.setState({
     checked: !this.state.checked
    })
   }
   handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
  
          this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});
           }
           
   render() {
    var msg 
    if(this.state.checked) {
     msg = "checked"
    } else {
     msg = "not checked"
    }
    return (
     <div>
      <input type="checkbox" 
             onChange={this.handleCheck}
             defaultChecked={this.state.checked}/>
     <Pagination
   hideNavigation
          activePage={this.state.activePage}
          itemsCountPerPage={10}
          totalItemsCount={450}
          pageRangeDisplayed={10}
          onChange={this.handlePageChange}
        />
     </div>
    )
   }
  }
  
  ReactDOM.render(
   <Note />,
   document.getElementById('react-container')
  )

 </script>
```

`

Also, sometimes it gives me out of memory error.
Browser hangs.

Comment: Pls share the detailed info about error

Comment: If I have <Pagination> component into my script, it says Pagination is not defined.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Pagination is not defined
    at Note.render (<anonymous>:55:25)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13663)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13625)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:14293)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:16319)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:16358)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:140)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:178)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:227)

Comment: Since I am unable to see your exact code, I have added a sample working of react code using cdn. Hope it helps :)

Comment: There is no `Pagination` component present or imported in your code.

Comment: How do I import another component externally with CDN links in my app? If I write - import Pagination from "react-js-pagination"; it gives an error. @GabrielePetrioli

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of how to use cdn for reactjs. Hope it helps :)

```
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
class Greeting extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const name = 'Johnson';
        return (<p>Hello world {name}</p>);
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <Greeting />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, this seems to work fine. But if you include another component like - <Pagination
   hideNavigation
          activePage={this.state.activePage}
          itemsCountPerPage={10}
          totalItemsCount={450}
          pageRangeDisplayed={10}
          onChange={this.handlePageChange}
        /> in render method, it gives an error that 'Pagination is not defined'

Comment: Can you please share actual code ? So that we can help :)